# custom RPC transfer problem

Tags: blockchain

I have some ETH in a custom RPC , how can I return it to the mainnet or any other RPC?

https://rpc.tenderly.co/fork/8b71c193-8362-465b-be4a-f8d036170651

Comment: Hey this doesn't really make sense, when you create a fork you clone the state, there is no transfer. So you can't transfer the cloned/fake eth to live mainnet. If something else is meant, can you clarify.